# Average of Standard Deviation

Tags: average, standard-deviation, means

How do I calculate the average standard deviation?

I have 27 standard deviations, each derived from 5 measurements per participant (27 participants), and calculated with SPSS. Do I simply take a mean of the SD's, or do I need to do something more advanced?

Comment: If you want the **average** standard deviation, you need to compute the mean $\sum std_i\over 27$

Comment: I thought it was this, thanks!

Comment: no problem, feel free to accept my answer to close the topic, or ask other questions you might have.